# How to get the average salary of each department from two separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two separate tables dept_emp and salaries. dept_emp contains the emp_no and dept_no while the salaries contains the salary and the emp_no. I think that I have to join the emp_no from both tables for me to get the dept_no of every employee then get the average of the salaries for every department.

```
SELECT `AVG(salaries.salary)`, dept_emp.dept_id  
FROM `salaries` 
INNER JOIN dept_emp
IN salaries.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no 
GROUP BY dept_emp.dept_id;
```

I tried this on but it doesn't work can you please suggest another way or concept for me to solve this?

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `INNER JOIN dept_emp ON ...` not `INNER JOIN dept_emp IN ...`

Comment: It should be `AVG(salaries.salary)`, without back-ticks. (You can have those around the column name salaries.salary, if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with **in** it should be **on**

```
SELECT AVG(salaries.salary), dept_emp.dept_id  
FROM salaries 
INNER JOIN dept_emp
ON salaries.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no 
GROUP BY dept_emp.dept_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `... INNER JOIN dept_emp ON salaries.emp_no ...`